# Docker secrets in build-time

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-secrets

Is there any feasible possibility to use https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/secrets/ inside Dockerfile during build time (NOT docker-compose specific .yml file)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Note: Docker secrets are only available to swarm services, not to
>   standalone containers. To use this feature, consider adapting your
>   container to run as a service with a scale of 1.

The answer is no. Secretes are only available in docker swarm. Swarm doesn't build images and it doesn't accept a Dockerfile.